# Правильно ли определены тропы и фигуры речи?

Tags: фигуры-речи, тропы

Выпишите из текста все тропы (изобразительно-выразительные средства языка) и фигуры речи (синтаксические средства выразительности).

И одним цветом белым рисует зима. Бедный цвет, но какая изобретательность... Эти роскошные завесы, снеговые глыбы, покрывающие от корней до верха большие и малые дерева; это множество жемчугов и брильянтов, сверкающих при свете солнца и луны; этот недвижный, величественный вид растений, как будто выточенных из слоновой кости; это многозначительное безмолвие и тишина; этот полумрак днём и полусвет ночью.

**Тропы:**

*олицетворение*: рисует зима;
*эпитеты*: бедный цвет, роскошные завесы, жемчугов и брильянтов, сверкающих при свете солнца и луны, недвижный, величественный вид растений, многозначительное безмолвие.
*сравнение*: растений, как будто выточенных из слоновой кости.
*оксюморон*: тот полумрак днём и полусвет ночью.
*гипербола*: снеговые глыбы.

**Фигуры речи:**
*Инверсия*: И одним цветом белым рисует зима.
*Синт. параллелизм*: эти, это, этот...

Answer (score 1):

У меня вызывает сомнение Ваш эпитет "сверкающих при свете солнца и луны", ведь здесь определение в прямом, а не в переносном значении. "Рисует зима" я бы назвал метафорой. А вот гиперболой я бы посчитал более пространную фразу: "снеговые глыбы, покрывающие от корней до верха большие и малые дерева".